# Uploading and parsing an xml file in JSF

Tags: java, xml, jsf

I want to upload an xml file via JSF Tomahawk and then parse it.

I have created the following form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
       <title>Import</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
       <h1>Import</h1>
       <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
           XML Datei mit den Kursdaten: 
           <t:inputFileUpload value="#{installationBean.uploadedFile}" />
           <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{installationBean.submit}" />
           <h:messages />
       </h:form>
   </h:body>
```

This is the bean:

package installation;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.UploadedFile;


@Stateless
@LocalBean
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class InstallationBean {

    private UploadedFile uploadedFile;


    public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
       return uploadedFile;
    }

    public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile value) {
        uploadedFile = value;
    }


    public void submit()throws IOException {
        String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getName());
        String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
        byte[] bytes = uploadedFile.getBytes();

        // Parse xml
    }
}
```

The file that i upload is an xml file.
How can I parse the xml?
In my code above I have got a byte array after uploading the file.
How can I convert this to an xml file and parse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following to parse this `byte[]` into a `org.w3c.dom.Document`.

```
   InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);  
   DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
   DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
   Document xml = builder.parse(is);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert it to a XML file. It's a XML file already. To parse it, just use either the Java SE builtin [JAXP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html) API or the Java EE builtin [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) API. If you actually want to save it on disk as well, just use `FileOutputStream` the usual way.

This problem has **nothing** to do with uploading files by JSF. You got that part successfully to work. You'd have *exactly* the same problem when you've obtained the `byte[]` by a `FileInputStream`, for example.